# Quit blender with dialog

Tags: add-on

My addon  code calls `bpy.ops.wm.quit_blender()`

And after that there is simply an exit from Blender. But I want to see the **standard Blender quit dialog**. Is it possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You would have to pass `'INVOKE_DEFAULT'` to call the invoke method of the operator:

```
bpy.ops.wm.quit_blender('INVOKE_DEFAULT')
```

[image]

Read: https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.ops.html#execution-context

Answer (score 2):

To close Blender **and** pop-up the UI window **"Save changes before closing"**, you need to run the code stated below.

```
import bpy
bpy.ops.wm.window_close()
```

**NOTE:** The option <kbd>Save Prompt</kbd> must be turned on, which can be found in the **Save & Load** category of the **"User Preferences"** editor in able for the code to work properly.

Comment: From what I understood, this operator only the active window : If you only have one open, it's technically the same as `quit_blender`, but it won't terminate blender if you have multiple windows open in one file. Good to know though :)

Comment: I think you are confused, quit_blender quits without bring-up the pop-up, save file window. Even with the save prompt I mentioned turned on. window_close on the other hand, does call the pop-up window, if the save prompt option is turned on.

Comment: But only if there is one open window was my point. People working with 2 screens often have several blender windows open with that file, and then your solution doesn't work, whereas the one suggested by brockmann does (ie call the `invoke` method rather than directly the `execute` one)

Comment: Are you referring to instances of the blend-file or multiple internal UI layout windows split to external windows. Confused.

Comment: I'm referring to windows that you open with Window > New Main Window

Comment: ... or for example the preferences window.